# Android Widget update

Tags: android, widget

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf)  I created a widget that should show the time. The java way works, but the service way doesn't.

**HelloWidget.java:**

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**UpdateService.java:**

```
public final class UpdateService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

        Date date = new Date();
        java.text.DateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance(
                SimpleDateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());
                updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, "Current Time " + format.format(date));

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, HelloWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

The **hello_widget_provider.xml** has this row: `android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"`

**Problem:**

The widget shows the current time but it's not updating (the java-way is).

My main goal is to update the widget at e.g. 18:56 every day.
Idk if this is the good way, but i tried to modify the onUpdate method like below, but it has a problem with ALARM_SERVICE: ALARM_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable

```
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
          intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 86400, pendingIntent);
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking back the time I asked this question makes me realize how much I learned in the past 1,5 years.

Since I have just been working with a widget in the last two weeks and I have just found this unanswered question of mine I decided to solve it. I hope it helps others.

The AppWidgetProvider should look like this:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";
    private PendingIntent service = null;  

       @Override
       public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {


           final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

           final Calendar TIME = Calendar.getInstance();
           TIME.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
           TIME.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
           TIME.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

           final Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);

           if (service == null)
           {
               service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
           }

           m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, TIME.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * 1, service);

    }

      @Override
       public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
               super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
       }

       @Override
       public void onDisabled(Context context) {
               super.onDisabled(context);

               final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
               if (service != null)
               {
                   m.cancel(service);
               }
       }

       @Override
       public void onEnabled(Context context) {
               super.onEnabled(context);
       }

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         super.onReceive(context, intent);

       }

}
```

The Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        buildUpdate();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void buildUpdate()
    {
        String lastUpdated = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", new Date()).toString();

        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.btn_widget, lastUpdated);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, MyWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, view);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, register the provider and the Service in the Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="MyWidget" android:label="Tutorial_Widget 1x1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.something.MyWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>    
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
        </receiver>

         <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but where are you set time which has to determine repeating interval?

Comment: `m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, TIME.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * 1, service);`

Comment: yes, thank you, I come get with this. I also interested how I can set specific time, at which updating will be carried.

Comment: You set the time in the AlarmManager then call the service every 24 hour.

Comment: There's a bug in this: onDisable is invoked from a different instance therefore 'service' will always be null. The alarm will never be cancelled using this code

Comment: Is there anyway to get this clock to update every second? It seems from what I've been able to find so far that the min update time you can set is every 30 mins, (way for android to save on battery power...)

Answer (score 3):

ALARM_SERVICE is a static field of the Context class. So type Context.ALARM_SERVICE or use a static import.

Remember that when you set updatePeriodMillis attribute value it's not guaranteed for your onUpdate method to be called with that period exactly.

Comment: I never had this problem so far. When i type as you said, there is a problem with getSystemService: "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type HelloWidget"

Comment: getSystemService(String) is a method of Context class. But widget providers are not contexts. They are broadcast receivers and retrieve context as a parameter in their methods. So you should type context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) in the HelloWidget code.