# widget updating at specified time with Service and CountdownTimer

Tags: android, service, android-widget, handler, countdowntimer

I need to update my widget at specified time everyday. Next updating must take place throgh 24 hours. 
I used `updatePeriodMillis` but it worked differently for different users. So I decided to implement robust solution. I've found this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866305/android-widget-update) and implemented CountDownTimer like this:

```
public class RepeatService extends Service
{
    FrequentlyUsedMethods faq = new FrequentlyUsedMethods();
     RemoteViews view; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        buildUpdate();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void buildUpdate()
    {
        String lastUpdated = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", new Date()).toString();
        Log.i("lastUpdated time", FrequentlyUsedMethods.getCurrentDate());
        view = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.main_widget);

        MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);
        counter.start();

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Widget.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, view);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_button, "done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_button,Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));

        }
    }

}
```

but it don't work for me. How can I solve it? Maybe by `Handler` using? Or  by `IBind` implementation?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is pretty generic. Does it give you any run-time errors? Does it simply not change the view at all?

Comment: `AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);` --- try to pass your application context rather than `this` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution: 
Service:

```
RepeatService  extends Service
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        buildUpdate(intent);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void buildUpdate(Intent intent)
    {

          setWidgetActive(context,true, Constants.WIDGET_UPDATE);

          Intent archive = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
          archive.setAction(Constants.ACTION_WIDGET_ARCHIVE);


          ArrayList<Quote> quotes  = new ArrayList<Quote>();
          quotes = faq.getQuotes(getApplicationContext());
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview,faq.getCurrentString());
          faq.sendNotification(quotes.get(quotes.size()-1));
          ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, Widget.class);
          AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
          manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);

    }
}
```

Widget:

```
public class Widget  extends AppWidgetProvider {

        @Override
        public void onEnabled(Context context) {
            super.onEnabled(context);
            this.context = context;

            FrequentlyUsedMethods faq = new FrequentlyUsedMethods(context);

            if(!getWidgetActive(context, Constants.WIDGET_ADDED))
            {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);  
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), Widget.class.getName());

            }
            setWidgetActive(context,true, Constants.WIDGET_ACTIVE);
            setWidgetActive(context,true, Constants.WIDGET_ADDED);

        }
        @Override
           public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
                   super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
           }
        @Override
        public void onDisabled(Context context) {
            setWidgetActive(context,false, Constants.WIDGET_ACTIVE);
            final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
            if (service != null)
            {
                m.cancel(service);
            }
            super.onDisabled(context);
        }
      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

           final AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          calendar.clear();
          long l  = System.currentTimeMillis() + 300;
            Intent i = new Intent(context, RepeatService.class);


           if (service == null)
           {
               service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
           }


           m.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, l, 1000 * 15, service);


      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with AlarmManager and Service using. Can post code, if someone needs...